# How to add different adapters to FastAdapter in android

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter

I'm using the android FastAdapter library from mikepenz
I have two adapters
1: AnimeAdapter : for displaying anime list
2: progress adapter : the one provided by the library

here is my AnimeItem for the AnimeAdapter:

```
open class AnimeItem(anime: Anime): AbstractItem<AnimeItem.ViewHolder>() {
    var name: String? = anime.name
    var nbEpisodes: String? = anime.nbEpisodes


    override val layoutRes: Int
        get() = R.layout.anime_item
    override val type: Int
        get() = R.id.anime_item_id

    override fun getViewHolder(v: View): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : FastAdapter.ViewHolder<AnimeItem>(view) {
        var animeNameTv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.anime_item_anime_name)
        var animeEpisodesTv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.anime_item_nb_episodes)

        override fun bindView(item: AnimeItem, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
            animeNameTv.text = item.name
            animeEpisodesTv.text = item.nbEpisodes
        }

        override fun unbindView(item: AnimeItem) {
            animeNameTv.text = null
            animeEpisodesTv.text = null
        }
    }
}
```

in my activity I tried to create the 2 adapter and add them to FastAdapter like this:

```
val animeAdapter = ItemAdapter<AnimeItem>()
val footerAdapter = ItemAdapter<ProgressItem>()
var fastAdapter = FastAdapter.with(listOf(animeAdapter, footerAdapter))
```

but I always get this error:

Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter Item in

```
fun <Item : GenericItem /* = IItem<out RecyclerView.ViewHolder> */, A : IAdapter<*>> with(adapters: Collection<A>?) : FastAdapter<Item>
```

Please specify it explicitly.

Comment: Have you tried `listOf<AbstractItem<*>>()`?

Comment: for FastAdapter i'm adding Adapters not items ...

Comment: Ah. I thought it works like Groupie, nevermind then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `with`, you can see `Item` isn't used in its arguments and so can't be inferred from them. You can either specify return type with the `Item` you want

```
val fastAdapter: FastAdapter<GenericItem> = FastAdapter.with(listOf(animeAdapter, footerAdapter))
```

as in [this example in README](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter#7-using-different-viewholders-like-headerview) or pass type parameters explicitly

```
val fastAdapter = FastAdapter.with<GenericItem, ItemAdapter<*>>(listOf(animeAdapter, footerAdapter))
```

Honestly, looking at code and particularly at [this cast](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/14ed13dc73e82d55420f1b30539d4ad8097da46b/library-core/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/FastAdapter.kt#L935)

```
fastAdapter.adapters.addAll(adapters as Collection<IAdapter<Item>>)
```

makes me suspect the signature should be fixed to

```
fun <Item : GenericItem> with(adapters: Collection<IAdapter<Item>>?): FastAdapter<Item>
```

which won't have this problem.

I posted this as an issue: https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/issues/838

Comment: Thanks ,using the first line helped me getting the footer adapter work
Even though i'm confused about the signatures too

Comment: The issue will be fixed with https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/pull/845.